# Typescript extends and implements use together when in multiple files breaks

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

When this code runs in a file it compiles without issue:

```
export interface Describe {
  describe: () => string
}

export class Base {
  constructor (readonly cat: string) {}
}

export class Child extends Base implements Describe {
  constructor (readonly name: string) {
    super ('Standard')
  }
  describe () {
    return `${this.cat}: ${this.name}`
  }
}
```

But when all parts are in separated files (`Describe.ts`, `Base.ts`only contains the code for those classes, and `Child.ts` is like so:

```
import {Base} from './Base'
import {Describe} from './Describe'

export class Child extends Base implements Describe {
  constructor (readonly name: string) {
    super ('Standard')
  }
  describe () {
    return `${this.cat}: ${this.name}`
  }
}
```

While TypeScript does not complain (typings are valid) the code breaks when running test with jest.
Got the following error:

> Base_1.Child is not a constructor

I imagine that the imports order break, but I can't see the error?

On a more complex example the similar pattern (A class extending another one and implementing interfaces) it did break as well with the following error message

> TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

while when all code is on one file it just works?

Here is the `tsconfig.json` I use:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "lib",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Here is the relevant part of package.json (since it breaks using jest):

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf ./lib && tsc",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "test:all": "jest --watchAll",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "lines": 95,
        "branches": 90,
        "functions": 95,
        "statements": 95
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "pretty-format": "^24.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.18",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.11",
    "@types/pretty-format": "^24.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.3.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.3.3",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  }
}
```

The test that breaks using jest:

```
import {Child} from './Child'

it ('A suite', () => {
  expect (new Child ('an item').describe ()).toBe ('Standard: an item')
})
```

Comment: What module bundler are you using? It's likely to matter.

Comment: @t-j-crowder No module bundler so far
Just `jest` (with `ts-jest` and settings for working directly with typescript) beside that it would be the `tsconfig` - do you need to see it?

Comment: Yes, we do. If I put those three files in place and compile with no `tsconfig.json` at all (all defaults), TypeScript (v3.6.3) has no issue with it and generates CommonJS-style ES5 code. If I tell it to target ES2015, it largely just strips off the type annotations and the interface (and again reports no errors).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did update OP with `tsconfig` - i keep it in esnext has i dont know what module bundler i will use. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Even with that `tsconfig.json`, TypeScript v3.6.3 is fine with it which makes me think it's a jest problem. You're quite near a [mcve] above, can you give us a minimal test to run with jest that causes the problem?

Comment: *"i keep it in esnext has i dont know what module bundler i will use. Could that be the problem?"* No, using ESM syntax is fine. It''s just a matter of ensuring the tools all play together correctly. :-) Sadly, if this turns out to be a jest thing, I'm not likely to be able to help. :-|

Comment: added the jest test @T.J.Crowder - thanks anyway for taking the time ;)